# Why have English words adopted the feminine version of French words with -if endings?

Tags: french

There seems to be a pattern with English words using the ending -ive to have been adopted from the French female variant.

Eg: [english <- french(masculine/feminine)]

- active <- act(if/ive)
- massive <- mass(if/ive)
- motive <- mot(if/ive)
- abusive <- abus(if/ive)
- competitive <- compétit(if/ive)
- positive <- posit(if/ive)
- progressive <- progress(if/ive)

Why is it that the English language more closely resembles the French feminine variants over the masculine ones?

Comment: Another one: naïf vs naïve.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The suffix comes from the latin suffix *-ivus* (pronounced [iːwus]). In French, Latin declensions gradually eroded, so the suffix became *-ive,* ending with a [v] sound (a common evolution from the Latin [w]) and a [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) (a common evolution from Latin declensions). The schwa further disappeared from the masculine form, and the final /v/ sound changed to [f], I think under German influence.

English acquired the suffix via [Anglo-Norman French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language) in the 13th and 14th century, in the masculine form: *actif*, *motif*, etc. Later, in the 15th and 16th century, the suffix was added to other words directly in English (some of which then made their way back to French, such as *competitive* and *sportive*). As these words were usually created by scholars who knew Latin, they used a suffix that was closer to the Latin original, thus *-ive.* Over time the older *-if* forms evolved to match the expanding *-ive* forms.

The few *-if* words in modern English such as *motif*, *aperitif*, etc. (and a few others that aren't from French) are 19th century additions, not survivors from Anglo-Norman, except *waif* (which is not constructed with an *-if* suffix) and perhaps *naif* (I don't know whether this one is a survivance or a later reintroduction).

Source: [*Latin Suffixal Derivatives in English: and Their Indo-European Ancestry* by D. Gary Miller (2006, Oxford University Press)](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199285051.001.0001/acprof-9780199285051), cited in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ive).

Comment: A good answer to an unresearched question.

Comment: Additionally, *motif*, *aperitif*, *digestif*, *massif* made it as a substantives and *naïf* can be found in English dictionaries. My best guess: they are later additions by educated people attending salons, where the French reference was intentional (in particular the beverages called aperitif and digestif). The word *massif* is likely attributable to the English tourists who went climbing e.g. the Mont-Blanc at the end of the nineteenth century.

Comment: @fralau Yes, I think all the remotely common *-if* words in contemporary English apart from *waif* are 19th or 20th century imports, from long after the Anglo-Norman *-if* forms had disappeared.

Comment: [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/naif) has *naif*  first used in the 1590s, so possibly one of the few words that actually is from early French rather than 'a word was taken from a root of French into a root of English'.

Comment: @TimLymington As far as I can tell, *motif* was introduced from Anglo-Norman, disappeared in favor of *motive*, and much later the architectural term was introduced from French. With *naif*, I don't know whether it's a survivance or a later reintroduction.